# SQL SELECT-only Query text validation

Tags: java, mysql, validation, select

I have a text that is a sql query. This text can only contain select statements(it must always begin with a "select").

The text should not alter the DB in any way. How can I validate it (to ensure it doesn't affect my DB and only fetches data from it) ?

I`m using Java with mySQL.

Thank you.

Comment: Simplest way will be to use [startsWith(str)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) method of String class.

Comment: Consider I could have nested selects.

Comment: It will check whether string starts with particular prefix or not. So I think sub select will not be a problem if you just want to check if query starts with 'select' word.

Comment: Indeed the query should begin with select but I want to prevent that somewhere in the nested clauses there should be no update,delete, drop, etc statements.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider creating a new user and `GRANT` it `SELECT` privilege only. Then you won't have to worry about parsing sql queries and checking whether they can alter your database.

On the other hand, if a query begins with `select` I don't think it can alter your database, because selects cannot contain nested updates or deletes.

Comment: Good point - you shouldn't allow for generic statements on the one side and then having to check security constraints programatically - as dogbane said, secure your statements by asigning rights to database user. If you really want to check your generic statement, I would propose parsing for all keywords you don't want to allow.

Answer (score -1):

You can use regular expression to do this.

```
String yourQuery = "SELECT";
if(Pattern.compile("SELECT .*").matcher(yourQuery).find())
{
// do stuff
}
```

Comment: What if I did `SELECT 'blah'; DELETE FROM ...`? :D